# Python & Beautifulsoup 4 - Unable to filter classes?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape shoe sizes from this URL:
http://www.jimmyjazz.com/mens/footwear/jordan-retro-13--atmosphere-grey-/414571-016?color=Grey

What I'm trying to do is get only the sizes that are available, e.g. only those that aren't greyed out.

The sizes are all wrapped in `a` elements. The available sizes are of `box` class, and the unavailable ones are of `box piunavailable` class.

I have tried using a lambda function, ifs and CSS selectors - none seem to work. My guess it's because of the way my code is structured.

The way it's structured is as follows:

The `if` attempt

```
size = soup2.find('div', attrs={'class': 'psizeoptioncontainer'})
getsize = str([e.get_text() for e in size.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'box'}) if 'piunavailable' not in e.attrs['class']])
```

The lambda attempt

```
size = soup2.find('div', attrs={'class': 'psizeoptioncontainer'})
getsize = str([e.get_text() for e in size.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and tag.get('class') == ['box piunavailable'])])
```

The CSS selector attempt

```
size = soup2.find('div', attrs={'class': 'psizeoptioncontainer'})
getsize = str([e.get_text() for e in size.findAll('a[class="box"]'))
```

So, for the URL provided, I am expecting the results to be a string (converted from list) that is all available sizes - at the time of writing this question, it should be - `'8', '8.5', '9', '9.5', '10', '10.5', '11', '11.5', '13'`

Instead, I'm getting all sizes, `'7.5', '8', '8.5', '9', '9.5', '10', '10.5', '11', '11.5', '12', '13'`

Anyone have an idea how to make it work (or know an elegant solution to my issue)? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a css [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo class selector to exclude the other class. Using bs4 4.7.1.

```
sizes = [item.text for item in soup.select('.box:not(.piunavailable)')]
```

In full:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.jimmyjazz.com/mens/footwear/jordan-retro-13--atmosphere-grey-/414571-016?color=Grey')  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')  
sizes = [item.text for item in soup.select('.box:not(.piunavailable)')]
print(sizes)
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What is you are asking for is to get the `a` tags with a specific class `box` and no other classes. This can be accomplished via [*passing a custom function as filter*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to *find_all*.

```
def my_match_function(elem):
 if isinstance(elem,Tag) and elem.name=='a' and ''.join(elem.attrs.get('class',''))=='box':
     return True
```

Here `''.join(elem.attrs.get('class',''))=='box'` ensures that the `a` tag has only class `box` and no other class.

Let's see this in action

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Tag
html="""
<a>This is also not needed.</a>
<div class="box_wrapper">
<a id="itemcode_11398535" class="box piunavailable">7.5</a>
<a href="#" id="itemcode_11398536" class="box">8</a>
<a href="#" id="itemcode_11398537" class="box">8.5</a>
<a href="#" id="itemcode_11398538" class="box">9</a>
<a href="#" id="itemcode_11398539" class="box">9.5</a>
<a href="#" id="itemcode_11398540" class="box">10</a>
<a href="#" id="itemcode_11398541" class="box">10.5</a>
<a href="#" id="itemcode_11398542" class="box">11</a>
<a href="#" id="itemcode_11398543" class="box">11.5</a>
<a id="itemcode_11398544" class="box piunavailable">12</a>
<a href="#" id="itemcode_11398545" class="box">13</a>
</div>
"""
def my_match_function(elem):
 if isinstance(elem,Tag) and elem.name=='a' and ''.join(elem.attrs.get('class',''))=='box':
     return True
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
my_list=[x.text for x in soup.find_all(my_match_function)]
print(my_list)
```

Outputs:

```
['8', '8.5', '9', '9.5', '10', '10.5', '11', '11.5', '13']
```

Comment: Why do you need that function? Doesn't it serve the same purpose `for item in soup.select("a"):if item.name=="a" and item.get("class")==["box"]:print(item.text)`?

Comment: Thank you for showing me this method - I will be using it in another part of my project. For this exact case I went with QHarr's method because it's simpler to implement.